# Subtract date time from current datetime of csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am trying to calculate the time difference in minutes from when the file was created and updated until the current moment to calculate the number of missing data. But I am unable to subtract them properly. My code is as follows.

The data in file looks like this:

```
DATE,temp1
2017-08-14 17:10:01,0.44
2017-08-14 17:15:01,0.62
2017-08-14 17:20:01,0.99
2017-08-14 17:25:01,0.85
2017-08-14 17:30:01,0.13
2017-08-14 17:35:01,0.24
2017-08-14 17:40:02,0.95
2017-08-14 17:45:01,0.65
```

And the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*
import os
import sys
import time

from time import mktime, strftime, localtime, sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def missing_data(expect, missed):
.
.
.
. 

def main():
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    with open('/home/kamil/Desktop/sensor1/temp.dat', 'rb') as f:
        read = f.readlines()[1:]
        for line in read:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            # print line
            start_date = line[0]  # type is str so i convert it to datetime
            start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt) # type is datetime.datetime  and here I need the first timestamp in the file only
            current_time = datetime.now()
            step_size = 5
            differ_time = current_time - start_date
            minutes_values = differ_time.total_seconds() / 60
            print 'minutes_values:::::::::::::::::::', minutes_values
            missed = int(minutes_values / step_size)
            expected = .........
            missing_data(expected, missed)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And if I print the minutes_values, it gives me results like this:

```
40.755
35.7553
30.755
25.755
20.755
15.755
10.755
5.755
0.755
```

But I just require the last value e.g 40.755 in this case. I am new to coding. Can someone help me in this regard that how to obtain the one single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a list to save minutes_values, then use the builtin max() to get the largest value.

```
def main():
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    with open('/home/kamil/Desktop/sensor1/temp.dat', 'rb') as f:
        read = f.readlines()[1:]
        minutes_values = []
        for line in read:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            # print line
            start_date = line[0]  # type is str so i convert it to datetime
            start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, fmt) # type is datetime.datetime  and here I need the first timestamp in the file only
            current_time = datetime.now()
            step_size = 5
            differ_time = current_time - start_date
            minutes_values.append( differ_time.total_seconds() / 60 )
            missed = int(minutes_values / step_size)
            expected = .........
            missing_data(expected, missed) 

    print 'minutes_values:::::::::::::::::::', max(minutes_values)
```

Comment: it says that float object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry, it is hard for me to test when you aren't providing example data otherwise I would have tested before posting. Please post the full traceback with a print minutes_values statement  somewhere in the loop to help with debugging.

Comment: i was making a mistake. i tried like this.............. minutes_values =  differ_time.total_seconds() / 60  and then minutes_values.append(minutes_values)........which give me this error that int is not iterable. . so i make it correct. thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a beginner, but it seems to me that the for-loop is unnecessary. It looks like you only want the first value returned by the loop (40.755) and that each successive value decreases by five, somehow related to your step-size = 5? If you change step_size, do the successive times change by that amount?

If the for-loop is necessary for something else, separate the two parts of the code: one to figure out the time diff, and one to do whatever the for-loop is doing.

Comment: if i remove the for loop, then how can i get the first timestamp of the first row?.

Comment: Well, it seems like in `read`, the items are somehow indexed, since you can loop through them. Can't you somehow specify that the `line.strip().split()` command be done on line[0], or something like that?